# vue js ajax inside another ajax is getting data but not rendering view

Tags: javascript, ajax, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-resource

There is a situation that I have to get extra data after my first ajax (in `mounted` function) in vuejs, I have put the second ajax in `if` condition and inside `success` function of the first ajax!

It is working and I see data in Vue Devtools in chrome, but data is not rendered in view.

Pseudo Code:

```
var vm = new Vue({
         el: '#messages',
        data: {
            participants: [],
            active_conversation: '',
            messages: []
        },

        methods: {

            getParticipants: function () {
                   return this.$http.post('message/get-participants').then(
                    function (response) {
                      
                        vm.participants = response.data.participants;
                        // if there is a conversation_id param in url
                        if (getUrlParameterByName('conversation_id')) {
                             // Second Ajax Is Called Here inside First Ajax
                             return vm.getConversationMessages (getUrlParameterByName('conversation_id')); // this ajax call is getting data but not showing in view  
                        }
                    }

            },
       
           getConversationMessages : function(conv_id){
              // Second Ajax Call to get Conversation messages
              // and showing them , works onClick
               return this.$http.post('message/get-messages/' + conv_id).then(
                    function (response) {
                        if (response.data.status == 'success') {
                            console.log(response.data.messages)
                            vm.messages = response.data.messages;
                            vm.$forceUpdate();
           }
        },


      mounted: function () {
            this.getParticipants()
        }

})
```

The Second Ajax Call to get a specific conversation messages is responding to `onclick` event and showing messages, but when this function is used inside the First Ajax success response (`getParticipants()`), its getting data correctly nd I can see in DevTools VueJs Extension that messages are set but view does not show messages, I have tried  `vm.$set()` but no chance.

**Update:**

The second Ajax is working with no errors and messages data property get filled (I checked Vue DevTools), The only problem is that view does not show the messages!! but when I do it manually by clicking on a conversation, second ajax is executed again and I can see messages!, I also tried `vm.$forceUpdate()` after second ajax with no chance.

**Update2 html part(the bug is here!!)**

```
<a vbind:id="conv.id" v-on:click="getMessages(conv.id)" onclick="$('#user-messages').addClass('active')">
```

Comment: You never defined `vm`? You should be getting a JS error.

Comment: @BrianGlaz  defined in the first line!  what do you mean?

Comment: by the way this is a pseoudo code and my code is working, I have rendering problem, I also tried `vm.$set()` function

Comment: Try `created` instead of `mounted`? I believe DOM is already rendered when `mounted` gets called. You can also try wrapping  `this.getParticipants` in `Vue.nextTick` function maybe.

Comment: @BrianGlaz  Tried `created` same result, I dont know anything about `Vue.nextTick` let me search!

Comment: @BrianGlaz, where do I exactly should use `nextTick` in my code?  Tried it  before calling second ajax with  no chance,   the wierd part is that I can see messages get from backend in Chrome DeveTools VueJs  Extension

Comment: Something like `Vue.nextTick( function() { this.getParticipants(); });`

Comment: yes, Tried this

Comment: What is the code for `getConversationMessages `?

Comment: @Bert Thanks for your attention, updated my code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the DOM is updated with messages with when you do the ajax request with only `getConversationMessages` and not placing
`getConversationMessages` in the success callback of the ajax request of `getParticipants` is the fact that an error is encountered at this line

```
this.participants = response.data.participants;
```

you are using a normal function in the success callback of the ajax request that's the reason `this` does not point to the vue instance
adnd `this.participants` gives you an undefined error. So use `vm` insteaad to point to the vue instance as you did in the rest of the program

```
vm.participants = response.data.participants;
```

**Edit**

```
var vm = new Vue({
         el: '#messages',
        data: {
            participants: [],
            active_conversation: '',
            messages: []
        },

        methods: {

            getParticipants: function () {
                 return this.$http.post('message/get-participants');
            },

           getConversationMessages : function(conv_id){
               return this.$http.post('message/get-messages/' + conv_id);
           }
        },


      mounted: function () {
            this.getParticipants().then(function (response){

                vm.participants = response.data.participants;

                if (getUrlParameterByName('conversation_id')) {
                    return vm.getConversationMessages (getUrlParameterByName('conversation_id')); // this ajax call is getting data but not showing in view  
                }
            }).then(function(response){
                if (response.data.status == 'success') {
                console.log(response.data.messages)
                   vm.messages = response.data.messages;
            });

        }

})
```

Comment: Tried  `vm.participants`  same results,  as I mentioned, there is no error, the second ajax is working and I can see ajax result `messages`  in console  and in Vue Devtools, i.e : `$vm.messages`  is filled with messages,  the only problem is that the view is not rendered and I can not see messages in page

Comment: @AhmadMobaraki can you refactor the code as in my updated answer

Comment: Thank you, I will try. (I'll let you know in 2 or 3 hours!!)  but i need my functions to be `success`  function inside. because they should  response  to `onclick` event independently

Comment: I refactored my code as you suggested, but same result :(

Comment: @AhmadMobaraki Please update your question with the corrected code.

Comment: @RoyJ What do you mean?  my code is working, Vmsi Krishna's code is working too. I mean the second Ajax is working and `messages`  data property get filled (I checked Vue DevTools), The only problem is that view does not show the messages!!  but when I do it manually by clicking  on a conversation, second ajax is executed again and I can see messages!  :(, I also tried : `vm.$forceUpdate();` after second ajax with no chance

Comment: @AhmadMobaraki `this.participants = response.data.participants;` is not going to work because `this` is not `vm`.

Comment: @RoyJ  Sorry, yes I know that, in my real code all instances are `vm` not `this`, I will correct the question.

Comment: @RoyJ and Vamsi Krishna Thank you very much, the problem was in html!  I updated the question again

Answer (score 2):

Call second http request after first is completed using http callback or you can use Promise too.

```
return this.$http.post(function(response){

   // first call
}).then(function(response){

// Second call
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the problem was in html!  I updated the question again

Answer (score 2):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#messages',
  data: {
    participants: [],
    active_conversation: '',
    messages: []
  },
  methods: {
    async getParticipants (id) {
      var response = await this.$http.post('message/get-participants')
      this.participants = response.data.participants
      if (id) this.getConversationMessages(id)
    },
    async getConversationMessages (id) {
      var response = this.$http.post('message/get-messages/' + id)
      if (response.data.status === 'success') {
        console.log(response.data.messages)
        this.messages = response.data.messages;
      }
    }
  },
  created () {
    this.getParticipants(getUrlParameterByName('conversation_id'))
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the problem was in html!  I updated the question again

Answer (score -1):

The problem for me was in html, I added a custom `onclick` event to the div element previously and this event was conflicting with Vuejs events.